# Prepend PHP file to all pages

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, analytics, prepend

I have an analytics file (in php) that I would like to prepend to every page on my site so that I can monitor which pages are visited.  How would I set up my .htaccess file to achieve this?

Currently I have:

```
<Files "*">  
php_value auto_prepend_file /analytics.inc.php  
</Files>
```

but it's not working as desired.

Also, if anyone can suggest a simpler way to collect site analytics, I'm all ears.

EDIT:
I would like the analytics file to be prepended to all files in all (sub)directories.  Currently only the root directory is having its files prepended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is incorrect for sure. it should be absolute path from the filesystem foot.

> if anyone can suggest a simpler way to collect site analytics, I'm all ears.

Your web-server already logs every request.
Only thing you need is to parse these logs daily and collect any stats you need.

Note that web-server logs every request, so, it has it's advantages and disadvantages. 
It will log not only requests to PHP files as it in your case but to static files too, like images, pdfs and such.
But it will also log every image on the page, so, one request to usual page will produce up to hundred records in the log file. So, you have to choose records to analyze.

Comment: fair enough, but I kind of wanted to match access times and ip addresses to user credentials, etc.

Comment: @ServAce85 you can make web-server log cookies for you where you can store these credentials

Comment: Sorry, obviously I'm new to this kind of stuff.  I don't totally follow what do you mean 'make web-server log cookies'?  Do you mean record a snapshot of their cookies at each instance in the log?

Comment: @ServAce85 adding cookie value to each log entry

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<Files "*">` and `</Files>` and just do:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /analytics.inc.php
```

Also make sure that the path to analytics.inc.php is correct, and its in the same dir as the .htaccess.

If it still doesn't work, seeing your apache error log file could help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Originally I just had the 'php_value...' line, but that was only being applied to the current working directory.  I wish to cover all possible directory and file listings.    I know that the analytics.inc.php file path is correct because it is correctly saving results for this root dir, but just not for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving an absolute path to the analytics.inc.php file in the .htaccess. IIRC, the prepend directive looks for the file relative to the file you are including it into.

Comment: Thanks @Jords for you contribution, but sorry, I guess I haven't been too clear... Here is a scenario to explain what I'm caught up with:
If a visitor goes to www.example.com their stats are recoreded via analytics.inc.php as specified by the root directory's .htaccess file.  However, if someone visits www.example.com/example2/index.php their stats are not recorded because that directory's .htaccess file does not tell it to prepend the file.  At least this is all based on my understanding of .htaccess - maybe I'm wrong.